# Post as page when commenting in a Facebook Comments Widget

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

To avoid posting with my real name on websites using the [Facebook Social Comments widget](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) I created a Facebook page with a funny name. I can also select this page by clicking the "Posting as my-real-name (Change)" link and submit a comment successfully.

However, the comment I posted does not show up anymore as soon as I refresh the page. When selecting reverse-chronological sorting (i.e. newest on top) my comment also does not show up anywhere. The page is marked as public.

Does Facebook somehow hide comments from pages without mentioning it anywhere? Does my page need to like the site to comment on it?

Comment: Could it be because the page/widget you are trying to post to has prevented showing comments from other pages in their feed?

Comment: Ah, didn't know that's possible. Could indeed be the case...

Comment: Does it still happens? If not, I think it can be closed as "the feature is no longer available" or "can't reproduce"